# Node JS : Can't access the data returned by MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, bcrypt

I am trying to compare the hash of a password in the database with a password submitted in a form.

So I have a login function which retrieves the user via his email address and which compares the hash of his password in the database with the hash of the password sent by the user (with bcrypt). Here it is :

```
exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
  async function checkUser() {
    const { user_email, user_password: clearPassword } = req.body;
    let sql = `SELECT user_password FROM users WHERE user_email=${user_email};`;
    db.query(sql, async (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(404).json({ err });
        throw err;
      }
      // const result1 = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
      console.log("Résult after transformation : ", result);
      console.log(typeof result, typeof clearPassword);
      const match = await bcrypt.compare(clearPassword, result);
      if (match) {
        console.log("match :)");
      } else {
        console.log("not match :(");
      }
    });
  }
  checkUser();
};
```

The problem is that every time I submit a password, I get an error : ;
Here is the error :
The password must be a string, and I have an object instead. I tried transforming it to a string with the commented line: // const result1 = Object.values ​​(JSON.parse (JSON.stringify (result)))

but nothing changes, result (or result1) is always an object.[image]

How to compare my 2 passwords please?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've done this, and it works:

```
const resultString = result[0].user_password
```

Now my object is a string.